# Display banner after showed this code 3 times

Tags: php, html, foreach, concatenation

I'm using SEBLOD(Joomla) and i have made template override for my custom list.

I have to display a banner after 3 times showed this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 title">
          <?php echo $cck->renderField( 'art_title' ); ?>
            <?php
               $stea = $cck->getValue('stele');
               if(!empty($stea)) { echo "<img src=\"/templates/protostar/images/system/$stea \">"; } 
                                   else{ echo ""; 
                                 }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="<?php echo $cck->getLink('art_title'); ?>" class=""><img src="/<?php echo $cck->getValue('imgunitate'); ?>" title="" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <div id="descriptionunitate" class="col-sm-9">
             <?php
                $minifyintro = substr( $cck->getValue( 'art_introtext' ) , 0, 185 . "...");
                echo $minifyintro
             ?>
             <br>
             <p>
                <?php   
                    $valueString = $cck->getValue('dotari_camere');
                    $valueText = $cck->getText('dotari_camere');
                    if(!empty($valueString)){ 
                    $images = explode( ',', $valueString );
                    $vText = explode( ',', $valueText );
                    foreach ( $images as $i => $image ) {
                    $value .= '<li class="list-detalii"><img src="/templates/sj_directory/images/travel/'.$image.'" title="'.$vText[$i].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" style="width:35px; padding:0 5px;" /></li>'; } 
                    echo "$value";
                    } else { echo "";};
                ?>


             </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <a href="<?php echo $cck->getLink('art_title'); ?>" class="detalii">Vezi detalii <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Can anyone help me pls ? I tried many times with foreach but i'm blocked on concatenate... :(

Comment: what is the problem with your concatenation? It looks fine, although your have 2 title attributes.

Comment: yea, i saw now ! Well i'm newby on php :))

Comment: was this the error you were having?

Comment: No. I would like after this display 3 times to display a banner.